# How to get yesterday in compile time?

Tags: azure-devops

As we know, we could set the variable like
$[format('{0:ddMMyyyy}', pipeline.startTime)] to get the today in compile time.
But how could we get yesterday in **compile** time, because I want to use it in some task's input.

I've tried pipelilne.startTime.AddDays(-1), but it looks ADO don't support it.
For '##vso[task.setvariable variable=AAA]BBB', it only takes effect in runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is not built-in variable or expression on Azure DevOps can get the date of yesterday.

As a workaround, you can try to add a job (or stage) as the very first one in your YAML pipeline to get the date of yesterday using related date command and set the date as an output variable for use in the subsequent jobs (or stages).

Below is an example as reference:

- **YAML**

```yaml
jobs:
- job: A
  displayName: 'Job A'
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    name: get_yesterday
    displayName: 'Get Date of Yesterday'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        YesterdayDate=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%d%m%Y')
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Yesterday;isoutput=true]$YesterdayDate"

- job: B
  displayName: 'Job B'
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    Yesterday: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['get_yesterday.Yesterday'] ]
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Print Date of Yesterday'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "Print Date of Yesterday:"
        echo "Yesterday = $(Yesterday)"
```

- **Result**
  [image]

For more information, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Use output variables from tasks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)
- [**SetVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)